# looking for $3D$ vector field satisfying certain projection conditions

Tags: analytic-geometry, vector-analysis, vector-fields, projection

I'm searching for a $3D$ vector field $V$ in $(0,1)^3$ whose parallel projections onto the boundary of $[0,1]^3$ are the following $2D$ vector fields:

The parallel projection of $V$ onto the $x-y$ plane will yield the vector field $\{x\log(x),-y \log(y)\}.$

The parallel projection of $V$ onto the $y-z$ plane will yield the vector field $\{y\log(y),-z\log(z)\}.$

The parallel projection of $V$ onto the $x-z$ plane will yield the vector field $\{x\log(x),-z\log(z)\}.$

I have a good idea of the general shape of the 3D vector field but I haven't been able to express it in mathematical form.

Comment: It seems you must put $-y\log(y)$ instead of $-y\log(x)$ in second line of your post.

Comment: thanks for noticing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COMMENT.-Just to consider the projection over the X-Y plane. Is it like this wath you want?.

Let the angle $\gamma$ be that of the directional cosinus with the Z-axis and **{i,j,k}** the base
we have
$$x\sin(\gamma)i+y\sin(\gamma)j=x\log(x)i-y\log(y)j$$ therefore $\sin(\gamma)=\log(x)$ and $\sin(\gamma)=-\log(y)=\log\dfrac 1y$. Then making $y=\dfrac1x$ you have for
$$\sin(\gamma)=\log(x) \text { and } xy=1$$ into the unit cube a solution concerning the X-Y plane.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need the projection of the vector field onto each opposite face of the cube to represent a valid solution. So I need 6 projections. I've included the example of one projection of the vector field onto the x-y plane

Comment: You are welcome.